# Упростить выражения if else

Tags: python

Всем привет!

Если есть `vendorid = 'synet'` то тогда в `ruturn` вставить переменную `synet`, если нету тогда не вставлять, как можно упростить это всё в одно действие, но быстродействие не потерять?

```
 vendorid = 'synet'

 if vendorid == "synet":
     return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (circuit_id, synet),())
 else:
     return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (circuit_id),())
```

Comment: Так будет читабельнее:

    param = circuit_id
    if vendorid == "synet":
        param = (param, synet)
    # else:
        # param = (circuit_id)
    return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, param, ())

Comment: мм

    return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (circuit_id, vendorid=="synet"?synet:null),());

Comment: Мне, кстати, кажется, что вариант автора читается на порядок лучше, чем все остальные варианты, предложенные в данном треде.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать не удивлюсь, если и с точки зрения производительности авторский вариант лучше

Comment: как то говорить о питоне и экономить на спичках в производительности... неэтично.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, кому как - мне в авторском варианте не нравится то, что приходится побитово сравнивать первый и второй return, чтобы найти отличия. Поэтому отличия лучше вынести отдельно, что я и предложил.

А в ответах не нравится то, что вместо чтения приходится разбирать код.

Вместо:

    if (isset($a['p1']) || isset($a['p2'])) {...}

мне приятнее читать:

    $hasP1 = isset($a['p1']);
    $hasP2 = isset($a['p2']);
    if ($hasP1 || $hasP2) {...}

@lampa, у автора во втором return`e не (circuit_id,null), а (circuit_id). (circuit_id,null) и (circuit_id,) - кортеж, (circuit_id) - число

Comment: @BOPOH Понятно, что это дело вкуса, но для того, чтобы понять разницу в вашем варианте нужно при чтении "загрузить в свой мозговой стек" информацию про существование переменной `param`, про то, откуда она берется и куда передается. В авторском варианте различие между `(circuit_id, synet)` и `(circuit_id)` бросается в глаза моментально и не требует дополнительных размышлений. Если `"vendorid == synet",` то передали `synet`, все просто и понятно.

Comment: @BOPOH а я думал, что это массив такой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно именно кратко, тогда можно использовать с-стиль.

```
return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (circuit_id, synet)[:((int)(vendorid=="synet") + 1],())
```

расшифровка:

```
vendorid=="synet" будет возвращать True или False

(int) превратит это в 1 или 0 соответственно.

 (circuit_id, synet)[:некое_число] - срез.  "некое_число" в данном случае по факту определяет кол-во элементов.
```

Насколько это будет быстро - спорно. Но если в Вашем коде проверок `vendorid=="synet"` много (ну хотя бы три), то хорошо было бы создать класс, который реализует логику, а отдельно, наследника для synet. Тогда этих проверок не будет (точнее - она  будет один раз при создании класса). Код будет чище и, скорее всего, действительно быстрее.

Comment: Если не сложно, можно пример использование классов?

Comment: пример использования классов вообще или для данного конкретного случая?

Comment: Для данного случая примерно, http://pastebin.com/haMLEwsQ

Comment: Если код работает - лучше думаю даже не трогать.

Что бы я сделал для начала. Я там вижу два раза проверку на synet. При этом результат отличается на одну переменную. Это можно вынести в отдельную процедуру. Вот результат - http://pastebin.com/4D0m64bz
Строки вида `"{0}".format` я бы поубирал. Смысла в них мало. И скорости добавит.

Там ещё есть, что рефакторить.

Заметил, что в коде сильно часто путаются пробелы и табуляция. У меня код разлетелся в результате, поэтому я не уверен, что оно нормально получилось.

Comment: Чем заменить тогда "{0}".format(), обыкновенной строкой форматирование "%s" %()? Где-то читал что рекомендовали использовать "".format()

Comment: я лично не вижу смысла в строке `'{0}'.format(nets['mask'])`, особенно, если `nets['mask']` уже строка. Тогда смело можно заменять на `nets['mask']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (circuit_id, synet),()) if vendorid == "synet" \
    else (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (circuit_id),())
```

или

```
return vendorid == "synet" and (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (circuit_id, synet),()) \
    or (radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK, (circuit_id),())
```

Comment: Не вариант, 13 переменных, даже если сделать перенос строк то не красиво будет.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая штука, которая называется [тернарный оператор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F#Python) Правда, судя по приведенной мной ссылке, в Питоне (надеюсь, я не оскорбил чьих-либо чувств, назвав его таким образом) он выглядит не так изящно и кратко, как в C-подобных языках. По поводу быстродействия - не могу сказать, во что раскрывается эта конструкция, но, скорее всего, она, будучи синтаксическим сахаром, разворачивается при компиляции в обычный if. Тем более, оптимизация таких конструкций - скорее всего [это несерьезно](http://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82)

З.Ы. впрочем, люди, знакомые с Python'ом, вероятно,знают что-то получше